# Uploading excel file the second time producing an empty excel file in S3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

```
import boto3

def upload(excel, bucket, file_name):
    S3_CLIENT = boto3.client("s3")
    fp = pathlib.Path(f"/tmp/{file_name}")
    try:
        fp.write_bytes(excel.get_workbook_data())
        S3_CLIENT.upload_file(str(fp.absolute()), bucket, 'file_key_in_s3', ExtraArgs={"ContentType": 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
    finally:
        fp.unlink()
```

This is my upload to S3 method. This is a lambda attached to API Gateway. so when I hit it the first time it's generating a proper excel file but when I do it the second time it's generating an empty excel spreadsheet and uploading it to S3.

`get_workbook_data` is a method that gets the information in the excel

PS: If I hit the same method after 5 mins again then I see a proper excel file.

Did anyone encounter the same issue?
Could someone please help me out?

I have tried using diff headers in postman but in vain

Comment: maybe first you should use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see if you don't get any error. OR first try it without `try/finally`

Comment: you can use `/` to join filename - `fp = pathlib.Path("/tmp") / file_name`. Or even like this `fp = pathlib.Path("/") / "tmp" / file_name`

Comment: @furas Tried `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` but that didn't print any exception because I see an empty file generated on S3

Comment: did you check if `excel.get_workbook_data()` gives something? Maybe it fives empty string. Some functions after reading data from file may need to use `seek(0)` to move to the beginning of file to get data again - without `seek(0)` it may read from the end of file and it gets empty data.

Comment: @furas I am gonna give it a try. But I do have a finally block that removes the file from the `/tmp` folder and again when I call the method its gonna generate a new file

Comment: you can run `unlink` without `finally`. All this is only temporary to check if there are some errors. If you get some error then maybe it makes all problem with empty file - and then you have clue what to fix. After fixing problem you can again use `try/except/finally`\